# Setting ComboBox Item Tag

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am adding `ComboBoxItems` like so;

```
foreach (var cntRef in presetList.Where(filteredPreset => filteredPreset.PresetReferenceFoxPro == 1).ToList())
{
    var newItem = new ComboBoxItem();
    newItem.Content = cntRef.PresetText;
    newItem.Tag = cntRef.PresetIDFoxPro;
    addCntRef1ComboBox.Items.Add(newItem);
}
```

This displays the text no problem. However I am having issues displaying the `Tag`. When I try to access the `Tag` like so;

```
if (addCntRef1ComboBox.Tag.ToString() != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(addCntRef1ComboBox.Tag.ToString());
}
```

Nothing is displayed. When I remove the `null` check the program crashes, so boviously the `Tag` is `null`. How can I add an `ComboBoxItem` with a `tag` I can access?

Answer (score 5):

You are assigning tag instance to `ComboBoxItem` not to `ComboBox` instance.

```
newItem.Tag = cntRef.PresetIDFoxPro;
```

And `newItem` is `ComboBoxItem` instance but then you are trying to access `Tag` property from `addCntRef1ComboBox` variable in line

```
MessageBox.Show(addCntRef1ComboBox.Tag.ToString());
```

Therefore program behaves correctly.

You need to access concrete `ComboBoxItem` in your `Item` collection of ComboBox, like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(addCntRef1ComboBox.Items[0].Tag.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I don't seem to be able to use `First()`. Do I need to add a `using` for this to work? It is saying that `ItemCollection` does not have a First extension method.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but you can access element collection by index. I've modified answer to acknowledge that.

Comment: The issue I see with that solution is that I want to access the selected `ComboBoxItem`, not just the first in the `Items` Collection. I've added my own answer below as I've fixed the issue.

Comment: Ok then, just in your question you didn't include what you are trying to achieve. So, I only tried to explain where problem lies. But I'm glad that you manage to come up with solution that suits your needs :) There's nothing much more pleasant that solving code problems by yourself :)

Comment: Sorry I should've been clearer with what I was asking! Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this problem myself using;

`SelectedValuePath="Tag"` in my `ComboBox` `XAML` then accessing it like;

```
if (addCntRef1ComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString() != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(addCntRef1ComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```